# VMWare workstation network - Connection to guest from host

Tags: vmware-workstation

i have an xp virtual machine in VMWare
It's configured for bridged network connection

In the office (or anywhere else for that matter) I can enter the IP address of the XP guest in the browser on the host and get the default application homepage.

Currently, I'm in a hotel with free wifi access.
To get the wifi, you need to enter a password.

When connected here, i can't get the default homepage of my app.
I can still ping the guest ip address from the host, but not use the application on here.

What settings do i need?

Comment: Did you authenticate to the hotel's captive portal in both the host and the guest?

Comment: no... but why should this matter..?
I don't want to connect to the internet on the guest, i just want the host to be able to access the guest

Comment: Because some captive portal systems give you unusable IP address information until you have authenticated. Since you are bridged, the hotel may be seeing the VM as a second device.

Comment: ok, but i didn't really want the hotel router having anything to do with my VM?
How can i bypass this..? Host only? or something like that

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up host-only or NAT networking.  If your host is Windows, you can run ipconfig to see the network information of the VMware virtual adapters. One of them will be the host-only adapter and one will be the NAT adapter. Each runs a DHCP server that will provide an IP address to your your VM if it asks for one.  Generally, they will be 192.168.xxx.0/24, with "xxx" being a random unused (on the network that your NIC was connected to at the time you installed VMware) network.

It's simple to do, just configure the VM (you can do this while it's running) and change the network adapter from bridged to one of the other two.  Then release / renew the IP in the VM and you should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Many hotel internet services only allow a single MAC address per room, set your guest to have a static IP in the same subnet as that given to your machine by the hotel, also match the host's DG and NM in the guest too. That should do it.